# Code not working(android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I know it's a pretty amateur question , but i am really getting frustrated: 
I am not getting an error but its just not working.(Ignore the bundle part)package com.example.project1;import android.app.Activity;

here's the java file

```
 package com.example.project1;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;

public class Tictactoe2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
EditText et1 , et2; 
String str1 , str2;
Button b1;
TextView tv2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ttt);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.et1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.et2);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tv2);
    str1 = et1.getText().toString();
    str2 = et2.getText().toString();
    b1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.b1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(this);


}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {

    case R.id.b1:
        tv2.setText(str1);
    /*Bundle bun = new Bundle();
    bun.putString("key", str1);
    bun.putString("key1", str2);;
    Intent intent = new Intent(tictactoe2.this , tictactoe.class);
    intent.putExtras(bun); 
    startActivity(intent);*/
    break;
}}

}
```

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an Exception, does the code not work as expected? Please provice a Stack Trace or describe exactly what is not working

Comment: getText in onClick of Button

Answer (score 1):

I guess you got `NPE`. You need to remove this lines

```
 str1 = et1.getText().toString();
 str2 = et2.getText().toString();
```

It's because you're trying to `getText()` from `EditText` and there is no Text in it. So i would suggest you move this lines under some `Listener events` where you get values after you set value in your `EditText`.

You implement like

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch(v.getId())
{
 case R.id.b1:
 str1 = et1.getText().toString();
 str2 = et2.getText().toString();
 tv2.setText(str1);
}}
```

Comment: @user3671445 `NPE` means `Null Pointer Exception` .

Answer (score 0):

```
 package com.example.project1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Tictactoe2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
EditText et1 , et2; 
String str1 , str2;
Button b1;
TextView tv2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.ttt);
et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.et1);
et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.et2);
tv2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tv2);

b1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.b1);

b1.setOnClickListener(this);


}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch(v.getId())
{

case R.id.b1:
str1 = et1.getText().toString();
str2 = et2.getText().toString();
    tv2.setText(str1);
/*Bundle bun = new Bundle();
bun.putString("key", str1);
bun.putString("key1", str2);;
Intent intent = new Intent(tictactoe2.this , tictactoe.class);
intent.putExtras(bun); 
startActivity(intent);*/
break;
}}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should place your "str1" String and textview and edittext code in your onClick.

like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch(v.getId())
{

case R.id.b1:
et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.et1);
tv2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tv2);
str1 = et1.getText().toString();
    tv2.setText(str1);
/*Bundle bun = new Bundle();
bun.putString("key", str1);
bun.putString("key1", str2);;
Intent intent = new Intent(tictactoe2.this , tictactoe.class);
intent.putExtras(bun); 
startActivity(intent);*/
break;
```

}}